# How do i change encoding settings with python

Tags: python

```
import bpy
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'H264'
    scene.format = 'QUICKTIME'
    scene.color_mode = 'RGB'
    scene.audio_codec = 'AAC'
    scene.audio_bitrate = 128
    scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
```

I have no idea how to get this to work right

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import bpy
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'H264'
    scene.render.ffmpeg.format = 'QUICKTIME'
    scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGB'
    scene.render.ffmpeg.audio_codec = 'AAC'
    scene.render.ffmpeg.audio_bitrate = 128
    scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
```

Also see the [API docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/).

Comment: Especially read this document about how to use the API docs: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_api_reference.html If you hover render settings, the tooltip says something about `RenderSettings.*`, and if you search for that type you will find this http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html - scroll all the way down and see the References section, there is says that `Scene.render` contains render settings.